# How to bind Selected item of Combobox to two different Property?

Tags: mvvm, binding, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I am developing project using MVVM pattern.In the project I have two viewmodel namely

1. CountryViewModel and  2. EmpViewModel

In countryviewmodel I have stored information about country,state,city etc.

In EmpViewModel I have a control which have combo box which displays country name and selected value is set to country id which are in CountryViewModel.

Here is code:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3"
             ItemsSource="{Binding CountryViewModel.Countries}" SelectedValue="{Binding Title}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CountryViewModel.SelectedCountry,Mode=TwoWay}"                               
             SelectedValuePath="Country_Id" DisplayMemberPath="Title">
    </ComboBox>
```

This is working fine.

I have local property country id in EmpViewModel and want to bind it to SelectedValue property of Combobox which I can get if I remove `CountryViewModel` from `CountryViewModel.SelectedCountry`.

But problem is I have another combobox for state which is dependent on Country combo box.
**Edit**: i.e in Country ViewModel I have called method GetAllState() when SelectedCountry changes.

So can I bind SelectedValue property of Combobox to both CountryViewModel.SelectedCountry from CountryViewModel and Country_Id from EmpViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a workaround**

I have write following method in an interface:

```
 public interface IViewModel
{
    T GetValue<T>(string propertyName);
}
```

In country view model I implement this method as:

```
 public override T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(this.SelectedCountry, typeof(T), null); }
```

And in Emp View Model I added following line:

```
newEmp.Country_Id = this.CountryViewModel.GetValue<Country>("SelectedCountry").Country_Id;
```